# Data passing between angularjs pages

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am working on an application which uses angularjs. In this i have a login page which lead up to home page. Login page is managed by **loginCtrl** which is further using **loginService**.

this is loginctrl (Login Controller)

```
'use strict';
angular.module('dreamflow').controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'LoginService',
function($scope, LoginService) {
    $scope.title = "Login";
    $scope.master = {}

    $scope.login = function() {
        var user = {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        };
        LoginService(user);
    };

}
]);
```

this is loginService

```
angular.module('dreamflow')
.factory('LoginService', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {
    return function(user) {
        $http.post('/login',{
                username: user.username,
                password: user.password
            }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $rootScope.user = response.data.user;
                $location.url('/');
            } else {
                console.log(response.data.errorMessage);
                $location.url('/');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

In the above code user details is coming after checking the success of response and then we are redirected to the home page. I want to access the user details coming in **$rootScope.user** in home page angular controller.

Comment: you could avoid using the rootScope by having the LoginService in your home page's controller. Then your home page's controller will have access immediately to response.data.user as the data comes in.

Comment: yeah i have tried to do so but i am unable to access the user data successfully. can you explain in more details how to do that.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.The controller is not in one angular module app but they are in two different apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a service which will hold the login username and the service will injected into both controllers as such:

[jsfiddle with '$scope'](http://jsfiddle.net/786c1hgr/2/)

Also, I find that using 'this' instead of '$scope' is helpful in not mixing up controller scopes between each other in case you use more than one controller in the same place. There are also other reasons.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div  ng-controller="ControllerOne as one">
        <h2>ControllerOne:</h2>
        Change testService.loginName: <input type='text' ng-model='one.myService.loginName'/> </br></br>
        myName: {{one.myService.loginName}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo as two">
        <h2>ControllerTwo:</h2>
        myName: {{two.myService.loginName}}
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
app.service('testService', function(){
    this.loginName = "abcd";
});

app.controller('ControllerOne', function($scope, testService){
    this.myService = testService;
});

app.controller('ControllerTwo', function($scope, testService){
    this.myService = testService;
});
```

[jsfiddle with 'this'](http://jsfiddle.net/786c1hgr/3/)

Comment: This does not work as the controllers are not in a single app but spread across two different apps.

Comment: I am not seeing 2 different apps mentioned in the original question; only 2 separate partials, each with its own controller @ritesh

Comment: correct..but instead of the hardcoded data like this.loginName="abcd" i want to read the $scope.username in service and pass that.